# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, adapter, android-context

```
Activity act = (Activity)mcontext;
            final Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            String s = list.get(position).phone;
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+s));

            Dexter.withActivity(act)
                    .withPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                        @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {

                            mcontext.startActivity(callIntent);
                        }
                        @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Accept call permissions first!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                        @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {/* ... */}
                    }).check();
```

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

is the error that shows up at the line `Activity act = (Activity)mcontext;`. The application crashes when this code is to be executed. Directly putting `mcontext` in `Dexter.withActivity` shows an error even before i run the app.

This is the code from an Adapter. The root activity is: `public class HodWithPhoneNumber extends Activity`

Comment: +Joe C, No I saw that question earlier. My case is different. The code i have provided is in an adapter.

Comment: Doesn't matter... You have assigned `mcontext` to an Application, not an Activity, as the duplicate states. Wherever you created the adapter, change the context you provided to be an Activity